# Can a countable union of empty interior closed sets equal an uncountable open set?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have an uncountable set $X$ with some topology $\tau$. Let $Y \subseteq X$ be open and uncountable. Is it possible for some countable set {$A_i$} to exist such that $\forall i,$ $A_i$ is closed and the interior of $A_i$ is empty, but $Y = \bigcup_i A_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this possible. Consider $X = \mathbb R$ with the topology generated by elements of the form $(a, \infty)$. Now consider the collection $\{A_i = (-\infty, i]: i \in \mathbb Z\}$. Each $A_i$ is closed yet with interior empty, the collection is countable and we have $\cup_i A_i = \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in a complete metric space, or a locally compact Hausdorff space, because of the Baire category theorem.  An example is $X = Y =\mathbb Q \times S$ where $\mathbb Q$ is the rationals and $S$ is an uncountable discrete space: take $A_i = \{r_i\} \times S$ where $r_i$ is an enumeration of the rationals.